# Laravel - Can I provide additional error variables if errors are thrown?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am using a custom FormRequest extension to validate my form submissions.  I have two forms on the same page.  Is there a way to append an error message (If it throws one from the rules inmy FormRequest) to identify WHICH form was submitted?

Right now I use some "if errors > 0" to determine if a form should load its old (just submitted) values or load the originals.  The problem is, when I submit form two, if it has errors, it causes form one to attempt to load previous values (which don't exist).

If I could have it do some sort of:
If error, then append 'errorform' => 'formA' to the $errors variable - it would help.

Ideas?

Comment: I did not understand anything, please, share blade code or whatever your forms are in. Usually, you do not share FormRequests nor URLs, so that is a code smell, that is why you are having issues solving this (wrong approach)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an easy way:

In my FormRequest:
protected $errorBag = "FormA";

Then, in my blade, I can use:
@if($errors->hasBag('FormA') to determine if the errors are from Form A